# How to slice a string to less then 500 character chunks but not cut within < > brackets?

Tags: ruby, string, split

I would like to split a string into less then 500 characters chunks and put it into an array. This is easily solved.

My problem is that the string contains html code and the split should happen outside of the < > brackets. Anyone knows how to do it?

That's what I currently got.

```
while article.length > 0 do
  textarr << article[0, 499]
  article[0, 499] = ""
end
```

Can someone tell me how to check that the split does not cut into the html code?
Thanks

Comment: A perfect solution will actually be a bit complicated. The fact that you want to do this indicates you're working around a design problem instead of solving it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have well-formed HTML (no unencoded `<` outside tags), you can check if you have cut a tag by finding an unmatched `<`. You could use a regex:

```
"Lorem <b>ipsum</b" =~ /<[^>]*\Z/
# => 14

"Lorem <b>ipsum</b>" =~ /<[^>]*\Z/
# => nil
```

In order to modify your splitting so that it doesn't cut tags you could use this regex to take variable-length chunks (noting that `=~` returns the index at which the match occurs, or nil if there is no match):

```
def chunk_length(chunk)
  chunk =~ /<[^>]*\Z/ || chunk.length
end

textarr = []
start = 0
while start < article.length
  length = chunk_length(article[start, 499])
  # probably should check for length == 0 here in case you get a really long tag!
  textarr << article[start, length]
  start += length
end
```

The check for `length == 0` might be necessary if you have very long tags; suppose you have something pathological like

```
<div class="lots of classes" style="some: 'raw css';" data-attribute="more stuff" ...
```

that could be longer than 500 characters on its own. Then, you will get to the point where `article[start, 499]` begins with `<` but does not contain the closing `>`, so that `=~` returns 0 (because it matches at the start of the string) and you will get trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: Real-world HTML contains unencoded angle brackets, which would throw this off.

Comment: Wow Andy, That is brilliant thanks. What I don't get is this check for length == 0 ?

Comment: @MarkThomas, agreed. Real-world HTML contains things like `<p>3<4</p>` which will be rendered by the browser correctly. This answer will have trouble unless it checks for `<` followed by the tag names in all HTML specs.

Comment: Agreed, which is what I meant by "assuming you have well-formed HTML".

Comment: Thank you so much Andy. It seems it's working fine. I checked for length == 0 and in that case just use length = 499.

Answer (score 3):

```
textarr = article.scan(/.{1,500}(?![^<>]*>)/m)
```

splits your string into chunks of up to 500 characters (as many as possible), reducing the size of the chunk, if necessary, to ensure that the next angle bracket is not a closing bracket.

Comment: This might split after a "<". And it will drop characters.

Comment: @MarkThomas: It won't split after a `<` unless there is no corresponding `>` ahead. As soon as unbalanced brackets enter the arena, all bets are off anyway. Regex is only suitable for non-pathological cases (and I'm counting unencoded brackets as pathological here). So yes, that's a limitation with any regex-based approach. But I don't see how this solution would drop characters - can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Example: The string `s = "outside <span class=\"big bold purple\">inside</span> outside2"`, when you apply `s.scan(/.{1,10}(?![^<>]*>)/m)`, results in `["outside ", "d purple\">", "inside", "</span> ou", "tside2"]`

Comment: @MarkThomas: Well, yes, if you only allow 10 characters, then that's a risk. But are there tags that are longer than 500 characters in real life?

Comment: Not commonly, but I have seen entire javascript functions in `onchange` and `onmouseover` attributes. Often with unescaped '<' or '>' characters.